# How do I merge duplicate nodes, using children in the comparison?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Test1.xsl"?>
<root>

  <RemittanceInformation>
    <EntityAssignedNumber>25</EntityAssignedNumber>
    <IndividualRemittance>
      <IndividualName>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
        <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
        <ExchangeAssignedSubscriberID>6650442525</ExchangeAssignedSubscriberID>
      </IndividualName>
      <ExchangeAssignedQHPID>38408SC221000101</ExchangeAssignedQHPID>
      <ExchangeAssignedPolicyID>26141334</ExchangeAssignedPolicyID>
      <IssuerAssignedPolicyID>39147964</IssuerAssignedPolicyID>
      <IssuerAssignedSubscriberID>101009913000</IssuerAssignedSubscriberID>
    </IndividualRemittance>
    <RemittanceDetail>
      <ExchangePaymentCode>APTC</ExchangePaymentCode>
      <PaymentAmount>214.00</PaymentAmount>
      <PaymentCoverageStartDate>2016-10-01</PaymentCoverageStartDate>
      <PaymentCoverageEndDate>2016-10-31</PaymentCoverageEndDate>
    </RemittanceDetail>
    <RemittanceDetail>
      <ExchangePaymentCode>UF</ExchangePaymentCode>
      <PaymentAmount>-43.04</PaymentAmount>
      <PaymentCoverageStartDate>2016-10-01</PaymentCoverageStartDate>
      <PaymentCoverageEndDate>2016-10-31</PaymentCoverageEndDate>
    </RemittanceDetail>
  </RemittanceInformation>

    <RemittanceInformation>
    <EntityAssignedNumber>26</EntityAssignedNumber>
    <IndividualRemittance>
      <IndividualName>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
        <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
        <ExchangeAssignedSubscriberID>0000442525</ExchangeAssignedSubscriberID>
      </IndividualName>
      <ExchangeAssignedQHPID>38408SC001000101</ExchangeAssignedQHPID>
      <ExchangeAssignedPolicyID>26141334</ExchangeAssignedPolicyID>
      <IssuerAssignedPolicyID>39147964</IssuerAssignedPolicyID>
      <IssuerAssignedSubscriberID>101009913000</IssuerAssignedSubscriberID>
    </IndividualRemittance>
    <RemittanceDetail>
      <ExchangePaymentCode>APTC</ExchangePaymentCode>
      <PaymentAmount>556.00</PaymentAmount>
      <PaymentCoverageStartDate>2016-10-01</PaymentCoverageStartDate>
      <PaymentCoverageEndDate>2016-10-31</PaymentCoverageEndDate>
    </RemittanceDetail>
    <RemittanceDetail>
      <ExchangePaymentCode>UF</ExchangePaymentCode>
      <PaymentAmount>-30.50</PaymentAmount>
      <PaymentCoverageStartDate>2016-10-01</PaymentCoverageStartDate>
      <PaymentCoverageEndDate>2016-10-31</PaymentCoverageEndDate>
    </RemittanceDetail>
  </RemittanceInformation>

   <RemittanceInformation>
    <EntityAssignedNumber>27</EntityAssignedNumber>
    <IndividualRemittance>
      <IndividualName>
        <LastName>Masterson</LastName>
        <FirstName>Gene</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>E</MiddleName>
        <ExchangeAssignedSubscriberID>0032171620</ExchangeAssignedSubscriberID>
      </IndividualName>
      <ExchangeAssignedQHPID>384111C001000101</ExchangeAssignedQHPID>
      <ExchangeAssignedPolicyID>26523035</ExchangeAssignedPolicyID>
      <IssuerAssignedPolicyID>38976623</IssuerAssignedPolicyID>
      <IssuerAssignedSubscriberID>101009869500</IssuerAssignedSubscriberID>
    </IndividualRemittance>
    <RemittanceDetail>
      <ExchangePaymentCode>APTC</ExchangePaymentCode>
      <PaymentAmount>448.00</PaymentAmount>
      <PaymentCoverageStartDate>2016-10-01</PaymentCoverageStartDate>
      <PaymentCoverageEndDate>2016-10-31</PaymentCoverageEndDate>
    </RemittanceDetail>
    <RemittanceDetail>
      <ExchangePaymentCode>UF</ExchangePaymentCode>
      <PaymentAmount>-30.50</PaymentAmount>
      <PaymentCoverageStartDate>2016-10-01</PaymentCoverageStartDate>
      <PaymentCoverageEndDate>2016-10-31</PaymentCoverageEndDate>
    </RemittanceDetail>
  </RemittanceInformation>
</root>
```

I have a ton of data in an XML file of the above format. A single person is represented by one "RemittanceInformation", but there are some duplicates. I would like to merge these duplicates and add the "RemittanceDetail" instances from all the duplicates into the first instance of that person. A person is uniquely identified by the "ExchangeAssignedPolicyID" number.

In the above example, number 26's two RemittanceDetail nodes should be moved to number 25's RemittanceInformation as they are both the same person with the same  ExchangeAssignedPolicyID. All following RemittanceInformation nodes should be incremented down to make up for the missing number.

I have seen similar code on S/O, but after a lot of hours and a lot of coffee I can't figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<xsl:for-each-group select="RemittanceInformation" group-by="IndividualRemittance/ExchangeAssignedPolicyID">` is a start assuming XSLT 2.0. Learn about grouping with XSLT 2.0 in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0 (see examples in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples) then you only need

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="RemittanceInformation" group-by="IndividualRemittance/ExchangeAssignedPolicyID">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="EntityAssignedNumber, IndividualRemittance, current-group()/RemittanceDetail"/>
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHd.

As for the adaption of the `EntityAssignedNumber` element, here is some change to achieve that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="RemittanceInformation" group-by="IndividualRemittance/ExchangeAssignedPolicyID">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="EntityAssignedNumber, IndividualRemittance, current-group()/RemittanceDetail">
                      <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EntityAssignedNumber">
        <xsl:param name="pos"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/RemittanceInformation[1]/EntityAssignedNumber + $pos - 1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHd/1.

Comment: I actually wrote that exact same code already, adapting an answer from another question (though I used stylesheet instead of transform), but I keep getting gibberish either way, as if it's completely not working:

http://prntscr.com/d7yjn1

Comment: I'm also using Saxon9he with the following command: java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:Test1.xsl -s:originalxml.xml -o:TestOutput.html

Also, this doesn't move the numbers down, I'm left with 25 and 27.

Comment: In retrospect, this seems like a completely different question. Your answer seems to be perfect, as shown by the online transform tool. Thanks :D

Comment: The stylesheet creates XML output, not HTML, so trying to view it in a browser does not seem to be a meaningful way to check whether it is doing its job. I don't think the first sample produces gibberish, it does the grouping as needed. I have added an improvement for the number adaption.

Comment: You are absolutely positively right, dear sir! Thank you so much, this is brilliant. :)

Comment: Sorry for bugging you again, but, the <IndividualRemittance> disappears with this xsl. How can I keep one instance of it on top? Further, how can I tell the xsl to just ignore RemittanceInformation that doesn't contain an "ExchangeAssignedPolicyID"?

Comment: Found it! Remittance was just misspelled! :P Awesome-o.

Comment: I created another question for the second issue, since I still can't figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635287/xsl-copy-for-each-while-ignoring-all-nodes-that-dont-contain-a-certain-type-of

Any thoughts? :S