# Xsl: Copy For Each while ignoring all nodes that don't contain a certain type of node

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="RemittanceInformation" group-by="IndividualRemittance/ExchangeAssignedPolicyID">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="EntityAssignedNumber, IndividualRemmittance, current-group()/RemittanceDetail">
                  <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EntityAssignedNumber">
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/RemittanceInformation[1]/EntityAssignedNumber + $pos - 1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I got this code from the super helpful martin-honnen on S/O, but one thing it doesn't do is, when a node of type RemittanceInformation doesn't have an IndividualRemmittance, it doesn't copy it at all.

What I would like is when there is an IndividualRemmittance, to group them together so there are no duplicates (The code does that already), but when it runs into a RemittanceInformation without an IndividualRemmittance, it should just copy it across normally.

What do I need to alter to make that happen?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at understanding the code? What part do you *suspect* you need to alter? Have you tried? What was the result of your try?

Comment: Well the grouping is done by "IndividualREmittance/ExchangeAssignedPolicyID", but I don't know how I'd just ... "Not" group when there's no IndividualRemittance present. I don't know how to set up that condition.

Comment: Okay, so you don't want to group them, but copy them. That's two things. Expressed differently, what you want to do is 1) to exclude them from being selected for grouping and 2) copy them separately.

Comment: Well they're already being excluded since they don't have the IndividualRemittance node, so that's great. Now to copy them separately while keeping the numbering convention, I don't know how. Do you?

Comment: I do, but I was hoping you would make the connection. :) The XSL element that copies nodes is `<xsl:copy>`. It's not all that difficult.

Comment: Right, that much I get, but do I need a separate for-each loop or do I need to append it in the same loop? Is there some way to say "If not IndividualRemittance present, then copy this instead" in xls?

Comment: The `<xsl:for-each-group>` can only group. It can't "not group". You must copy the items you want to copy in a separate step.

Comment: Then I'd still need a "does not contain node of type" as a condition.

Comment: Exactly, and that's a very basic XPath condition. When you search for it, you will find this has been asked and answered many times in the past. For example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464272/xpath-find-node-that-does-not-contain-child

Comment: One final question (I hope). How would I insert that condition [not(IndividualRemittance)] within a for-each xsl? Presumably somewhere within select="RemittanceInformation"?

Comment: There is not even a need for a for-each. You can copy any number of nodes in a single step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tomalak's help, I made it work! :D

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
     <xsl:variable name="countComp" select="count(//RemittanceInformation[not(IndividualRemittance)])"/>
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="RemittanceInformation[not(IndividualRemittance)]">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:for-each-group select="RemittanceInformation" group-by="IndividualRemittance/ExchangeAssignedPolicyID">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="EntityAssignedNumber, IndividualRemittance, current-group()/RemittanceDetail">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos+$countComp"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EntityAssignedNumber">
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="/root/RemittanceInformation[1]/EntityAssignedNumber + $pos - 1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: That was a hard coded number I used. Properly, it should be a variable. I'll update it right now.